# Rails & Angular: Unable to get parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, parameters, request, http-post

I am unable to get params from the request. Here my code-

**Js code**

```
      loginApp = angular.module("loginApp",[]);

  loginApp.controller("loginController",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.username = "";
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.login = function(){
      $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      username = $scope.username
      password = $scope.password
      params = {username: username, password: password};
      $http.post('api/login',params)
      .then(function(response) {
          $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
      });
    }
  });
```

As you can I am making a post request to api/login.

**Controller code-**

```
  def login
username = params[:username]
password = params[:password]
puts username.inspect
puts password.inspect
```

end

**Result**-

```
Started POST "/api/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-05 00:20:31 +0900
Processing by ApiController#login as HTML
Parameters: {"{\"username\":\"jsxbhjcxb`\",\"password\":\"jcbsjcb\"}"=>"     [FILTERED]"}
nil
nil
```

I don't know why it is showing nil. Sorry I new to angular and rails.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you send your data in JSON format

So make this change

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```